# How do I create a line graph using multiple variables when the multiple variables are all in the same column?

Tags: r, dataframe, linegraph

[image: WorkingData]

```
structure(list(Sample.Id = c(NA, "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2",
```

"2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"
), Sampling..Date = c(NA, "08-Sep-14", "14-Oct-14", "02-Nov-14",
"21-Nov-14", "03-Dec-14", "15-Dec-14", "11-Jan-15", "08-Feb-15",
"01-Mar-15", "06-Apr-15", "03-Sep-14", "08-Sep-14", "14-Oct-14",
"02-Nov-14", "21-Nov-14", "03-Dec-14", "15-Dec-14", "11-Jan-15",
"26-Jan-15"), Tot.P = c("µg/ml", "0.002", "0.017", "0.035",
"0.04", "0.059", "0.155", "0.021", "0.022", "0.025", "<0.009",
"0.021", "0.003", "0.036", "0.141", "0.041", "0.044", "0.01",
"0.023", "0.016"), DOC = c("µg/ml", NA, "12.3", "13.4", "12.5",
"9.9", "14.7", "8.8", "8.3", "0.026", "7.5", "13.4", NA, "14.6",
"16.6", "14.7", "12.6", "12.6", "10.6", "11.4"), Tot.N = c("µg/ml",
NA, "3.63", "4.12", "3.98", "4.08", "3.38", "3.63", "4.88", "8.3",
"2.74", "2.48", NA, "3.07", "3.38", "3.3", "3.43", "2.19", "2.77",
"4.25"), DOC.1 = c("µg/ml", "13.6", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, "14.44", "16.85", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Tot.P.1 = c("µg/ml",
"0.053", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.08", "0.071",
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Total.N = c("µg/ml", "3.363", NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2.645", "2.637", NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame"

I have a set of water quality data from 2014-2022 over different sites and different time periods. Each site has a different monitoring period and the data was analysed using two different devices of which there are only two periods of overlap where the samples were analysed using both machines. I am trying to plot a time series showing the P, N and DOC across each site over time and shade in the areas where one machine was used instead of another. This is all a bit complicated and I am so new to R so have been running in circles for a week. My problem is I am unsure how to select the section of a column I need to create the variable I want so it makes sense.

I have tried to look it up on blogs but can't seem to mash the different pieces of advice together to make it work. Any tips would be much appreciated. Here is the data that I'm on about.

Comment: I suspect you will either need to re-arrange your data prior to plotting and/or use the 'group' aesthetic in ggplot to get your desired result. Could you please add some example data so that we can better answer your question? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi I managed to attach it, apologies I thought I already had!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, can you upload the code to create your problem please so we can replicate it without having to type out your dataframe? See here for why uploading data as an image is generally a bad idea: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: I think you'll face some issues with your first row as that will coerce all the remaining values below into character, rather than being numeric. Same will happen with your row 11 value for Tot.P of `<0.009`.

Comment: Hi guys, I attached a copy of the first few lines of data, apologies for the delay I had to google how to do it :/ I'll see if I can change the column characteristics to be numeric instead

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need to clean up your data to fit this solution, but your basic way about this is pivoting from wide to long form.

Then you need to ensure that your dates are the propper POSIXct format.

Then it is just a matter of grouping by your relevant variables and plotting with `geom_line()`

I added the `facet_grid` to separate by `Sample.Id`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: pakke 'ggplot2' blev bygget under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: pakke 'tidyr' blev bygget under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: pakke 'purrr' blev bygget under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: pakke 'dplyr' blev bygget under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: pakke 'stringr' blev bygget under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: pakke 'forcats' blev bygget under R version 4.2.2

df <- structure(list(Sample.Id = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
                                    "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), 
                      Sampling..Date = c("08-Sep-14", "14-Oct-14", "02-Nov-14", 
                                         "21-Nov-14", "03-Dec-14", "15-Dec-14", "11-Jan-15", "08-Feb-15", 
                                         "01-Mar-15", "06-Apr-15", "03-Sep-14", "08-Sep-14", "14-Oct-14", 
                                         "02-Nov-14", "21-Nov-14", "03-Dec-14", "15-Dec-14", "11-Jan-15", 
                                         "26-Jan-15"), Tot.P = c("0.002", "0.017", "0.035", "0.04", 
                                                                 "0.059", "0.155", "0.021", "0.022", "0.025", "<0.009", "0.021", 
                                                                 "0.003", "0.036", "0.141", "0.041", "0.044", "0.01", "0.023", 
                                                                 "0.016"), DOC = c(NA, "12.3", "13.4", "12.5", "9.9", "14.7", 
                                                                                   "8.8", "8.3", "0.026", "7.5", "13.4", NA, "14.6", "16.6", 
                                                                                   "14.7", "12.6", "12.6", "10.6", "11.4"), Tot.N = c(NA, "3.63", 
                                                                                                                                      "4.12", "3.98", "4.08", "3.38", "3.63", "4.88", "8.3", "2.74", 
                                                                                                                                      "2.48", NA, "3.07", "3.38", "3.3", "3.43", "2.19", "2.77", 
                                                                                                                                      "4.25"), DOC.1 = c("13.6", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                         NA, "14.44", "16.85", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 2:20, class = "data.frame")


df |> 
  mutate(Tot.P = str_replace(Tot.P, "<", ""),
         across(Tot.P:DOC.1, as.numeric),
         Sampling..Date = as.POSIXct(Sampling..Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")) |> 
  select(-c(DOC.1)) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Tot.P, DOC, Tot.N)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sampling..Date, y = value, group = name, col = name)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(~Sample.Id)
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>